# How to index a PyArrow Table?

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

Im currently using Arrow in my machine learning model to read data from Parquet. Currently I'm trying to figure out how to get certain records from an Arrow table. I see that an Arrow Table has a "Take" [api](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table.take) , but I'm not sure how to use it. I tried passing in an int index, but when I try that Im getting the following exception:

`Got unexpected argument type <class 'int'> for compute function`

Anyone know how I can read records from an arrow table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `take()` method of a pyarrow Table needs an array-like of indices (and not a single integer index):

```py
>>> import pyarrow as pa
>>> table = pa.table({'a': range(5)})
>>> table.to_pandas()
   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4

>>> table.take([0, 2]).to_pandas()
   a
0  0
1  2
```